# Making socket communication using bin_prot

Tags: sockets, ocaml, communication

I want to make Socket communication using bin_prot in OCaml. However, I can't find any detailed explanation or example to do that. I made Socket communication in the other way before, so I know the flow of it. 
Do you have good explanations or examples to make Socket communication using bin_prot in OCaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, bin_prot is just a serialization protocol, and doesn't depend on whatever you're using for a transport layer. Basically, to serialize a value to string, you can use `Binable.to_string` function (or `Binable.to_bigstring`). It accepts a packed module. For example, to serialize a set of ints, do the following:

```
 let str = Binable.to_string (module Int.Set) mine_set;
```

where `mine_set` is the set of integers.

If you have your arbitrary type, that implements bin_prot, then it will work the same. An example would be:

```
module My_data = struct
  type t = int * string with bin_io
end
let str = Binable.to_string (module My_data) (42,"answer")
```

Comment: Thank you. Then, if I don't know the type of the data that I want to serialize,  what should I do? I mean the program `let f x = let str = Binable.to_string (module ...) x in str`. In this case, how can I know the type x?

Comment: s / the type x / the type of x

Comment: If you don't know the type, you can't serialize it with binprot. The type of `x` is equal to type `M.t` of the module `M` that is passed as a first argument of `to_string` function, e.g.,  `(module M)`. For example, if you pass `(module Int.Set)`, a type of a second argument should be `Int.Set.t`, etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. Can I make module `M` and the type `M.t` when compiling a program? I want to write `let f x = let str = Binable.to_string (module ...) x in str` in the program, so `x` gets a concrete type, e.g., int * int, when compiling. I think if I can do that, I can write `let f x = let str = Binable.to_string (module ...) x in str` in the program.

Comment: I mean that the function `f` is used in some places in the program. For example, `let f x = let str = Binable.to_string (module ...) x in str in .... f (2, 2) ...`. In this case, x gets the type `int * int` when compiling. I want to make module `M` and the type `M.t` after  x gets the type `int * int`